# Как объединить несколько значений в одну строку?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Начинаю изучать Objective-C (после Java) и столкнулся с такой проблемой: не знаю, как форматировать строку, конвертировать типы и объединить строки.
В общем, хочу вывести примерно такую строку (как бы это выглядело на Java):

```
 return "const value" + intVariable + stringVariable;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С использованием NSString:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", @"constant string", 12345];
```

Собственно, суть та же, что и обычный sprintf. Но есть огромный плюс — длину за Вас посчитают!

[Тут](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i) всё есть :).

Answer (score 0):

Я никогда в жизни не встречался с objective-c, но предполагаю, что там всё так же как и в обычном C :).

Если не использовать никакой специальный класс для строк, а обходиться только char*, то примерно так:

```
char *result = new char[1024];
sprintf(result, "%s%d%s", "const value", intVariable, stringVariable);
```

Собственно, что делает этот код:

Во-первых, мы заводим буфер, в который положим итоговую строку. Число 1024 — это я из головы взял. Главное, чтобы места хватило. Скорее всего, имеет смысл вычислить его как длину Вашей константной строки плюс strlen(stringVariable) плюс несколько символов, чтобы число точно влезло.

Далее, используем функцию sprintf (чтобы её заполучить надо включить stdio.h). Она кладёт в свой первый аргумент строку, соответствующую формату, указанному вторым аргументом, собрав её из всех остальных. Этот самый страшный [printf-формат](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) используется очень много где, так что с ним полезно быть знакомым :)

Comment: Класс для строк NSString - стандартный для obj-C. Там вроде есть класс Util какой-то...